# url.openstream() or urlconnection.getinputstream() raise nullpointerexception on valid URL

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

For an android application I am trying to change an URL of an XML because of a new server, but the content is the same.
I used to do this:

```
InputSource ins = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
```

This used to work and for a few days still does, while the old URL is available on on the old server. But when i change the URL of the XML I get an NullPointerException on the row above.

I am sure rssUrl is not null, I printed the value of it an is just the working URL. I validated the XMl and the XML is valid, but this doesn't really matter because the problem is raised before the parsing starts.

One of the things I tried was something like this:

```
Urlconnection urlConnection= rssUrl.openurlconnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
inputsource ins = new inputsource(in);
```

but this raised an nullpointerexception as well.

I read some things [about downgrading my Java to 6](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/Scg13DQoFxw/Zxe8m_zBy0wJ) (currently i am using 7). But i don't really feel like it and can't imagine why it would work.

**edit:**
I tried downgrading to java se 6 but didn't work.

Does anyone know how this error is possible and how to resolve it?

stack:

```
12-28 22:14:53.635: W/System.err(6949): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 22:14:53.725: W/System.err(6949):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.hashCode(HttpConnection.java:343)
12-28 22:14:53.725: W/System.err(6949):     at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:298)
12-28 22:14:53.725: W/System.err(6949):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:67)
12-28 22:14:53.725: W/System.err(6949):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
12-28 22:14:53.725: W/System.err(6949):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
12-28 22:14:53.725: W/System.err(6949):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at com.hera.ontdekdelft.StartUp$LoadData.doInBackground(StartUp.java:610)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at com.hera.ontdekdelft.StartUp$LoadData.doInBackground(StartUp.java:1)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at j.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-28 22:14:53.735: W/System.err(6949):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
ava.util
```

**Solution**

Underscores in the URL caused android to fail. My solution was editing the url of the XML file so rssUrl.openstream() would work again. problem solved, thanks to [Kiruwka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2358786/kiruwka)

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace and the initialization and type of `rssUrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the trace you provided it seems that `uri.getHost()` is null, throwing `NPE` to you from internal implementation. You could verify if it is null by outputting :

```
Log.d(TAG, "host = " + rssUrl.getHost());
```

before opening connection. If it is null, fix your url.

**Update**
I saw several similar issues for cases when host string contains spaces or '_' characters, for example [this known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16895), or [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15558525/2358786) for underscore symbols issue.

Comment: First part you were right, had removed it in the code and tried to duplicate it here and made a mistake. I tried the rssUrl.getHost() but it just gives back the host, not null. Should the host contain http:// ? I get the part of the url before the backslash, without http://

Comment: could you please give your host string ?

Comment: @Jasper. The problem is with underscore symbol in host string. You will have to change that, I am afraid. See update to my answer

Comment: I'll try it, let you know. Thanks in advance! Had no idea that could bring trouble...

Comment: I imagine it might be already fixed on newer android platforms. Which android version you are running your code on ?

Comment: my current testing device is running android 4.0.3

Comment: too bad, that means that bug is not fixed on android at all. So, you have to change your hostname to eliminate underscores, I don't see other way.

Comment: Hello, i am getting one issue. in my case connection.getResponseCode() returns 200 and connection.getResponseMessage() returns OK. but when i am trying to use BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
responseString1 = in1.readLine();    in1.readLine() always returning null