# url.openStream() gives NullPointerException for just one url

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

please do not mark it as a duplicated because I have already searched Stackoverflow before posting it, and found this solution,

[url.openstream() or urlconnection.getinputstream() raise nullpointerexception on valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817383/url-openstream-or-urlconnection-getinputstream-raise-nullpointerexception-on)

but this solution doesn't work either.

The problem is i am trying to `openStream` on this url > `http://www.techworld.com/security/rss` for my Android App.

but it always give `NullPointerException`.

I first checked the connection to see if the connection is successful,

```
connection.getResponseCode();
```

and it return `200` so the connection is ok.

Then according to the available solutions, I changed the JRE version from 1.7 to 1.6 but this still don't work.

When I try to `openStream` other urls then they work absolutely fine with the same code but the above link gives `NPE`.

this is the code,

```
URL mylink = new URL ("http://www.techworld.com/security/rss");

HttpURLConnection connection;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) myLink.openConnection();   
connection.connect();

if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    try {
        domObject = new DOM(myLink.openStream());
        domObject.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,e+" " + host);
    }    
}
```

in the above code, `host = myLink.getHost();`.

one more thing i would like to mention that, when I run this code as a Java project instead of Android project then it loads finds and do not throw `NPE`.

What could be the problem here ?

This is the logCat, it only shows one line error,

```
01-21 20:46:11.575: E/testApp(30335): java.lang.NullPointerException www.techworld.com
```

Comment: Show the stack trace of the NPE? From the snippet above, the only logical NPE comes from the `connection.connect()` line

Comment: no , it shows `NPE` on `openStream` line, as you can see the `catch` block of the updated code. I have also added Logcat , please see.
I would also like to mention that other URLs load absolutely fine.

Comment: It would actually be more useful if you didn't catch the error in the catch block in this case so that we had a full LogCat stacktrace to look at.  So that we know whether it specifically targets lets say the myLink.openStream() or  the .start() in the following line.  But we will assume you are telling us the connect() line is the culprit.

Comment: @JaySnayder, actually i tried that but Eclipse gives error that `Unhadled exception type IOException.`

Comment: then use e.printStackTrace() instead custom Log.d ... (inside catch)

Comment: @bhuvesh Thats good.  That provides us with better information on the stacktrace that gets printed out in Logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least this code worked:

```
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.techworld.com/security/rss");
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.connect();
    if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(inputLine).append("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            bufferedReader.close();
        }

        System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think your code tries to open connection twice. While the first connection is not closed, you try connect another **myLink.openStream()**. It may be better just using **connection.getInputStream()**.